# Flutter-Firebase: Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a callable function to my app but what I get is Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object. I tried with another very simple function and the result is always the same. Here is the function:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date"];
});
```

And this is the call:

```dart
Future<void> checkCallable() async {
    debugPrint((await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('sendMessage').call()).data);
  }
```

And finally the error:

```
E/flutter (26536): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object.
E/flutter (26536): 
E/flutter (26536): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (26536): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23:24)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #4      _MyHomePageState.checkCallable (package:league_tracker/main.dart:79:17)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): 
E/flutter (26536): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (26536): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23:24)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #4      _MyHomePageState.checkCallable (package:league_tracker/main.dart:79:17)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): 
I/flutter (26536): Got null accent color.
D/InputTransport(26536): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=146
E/flutter (26536): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object.
E/flutter (26536): 
E/flutter (26536): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (26536): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23:24)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #4      _MyHomePageState.checkCallable (package:league_tracker/main.dart:79:17)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): , stack trace: #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (26536): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23:24)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536): #4      _MyHomePageState.checkCallable (package:league_tracker/main.dart:79:17)
E/flutter (26536): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26536):
```

EDIT: In the function I tried also to return something like:

```js
return {message: text};
```

or

```js
return "text";
```

Comment: can you refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66830084/15774176) is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav no becuase that link shows how to retrieve data correctly in the request

Comment: is you issue similar to [this](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/245) if not can you briefly explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Response must be JSON object, try something like this:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {result: ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date"]};
});
```

See [Response body](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#response_body) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually there were many trials with different return types like map and simple strings before the one I posted . I copied the example with the list from this link https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/.  I just tried with your proposal but I still got the same error.

Comment: @user18309290 Actually returning the Array does work. The firebase-functions SDK encodes the returned value as `{"data":["Apple","Banana","Cherry","Date"]}`.

Comment: @Zan is this issue resolved?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav no